# What do the partial derivates mean in the formulation of total derivate?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In the total derivate expression of a function $f(x,y,z)$ where $x, y$ and $z$ are functions of $t$, what do the partial derivates $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$,  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ mean? Since $x, y, z$ are functions of $t$, it is impossible to keep one of x, y and z varying and others constant (which is what is done while computing the partially derivatives).

Total derivative of $f$ w.r.t. t:
$$
 \frac{d f}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}
$$

Comment: Just realized that you formula is not correct... the last term should not be there. The chain rule in this case is $$ \frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{dz}{dt}.$$

Comment: You wrote the formula as if $f$ was a function of 4 variables and this is not correct. maybe the source of confusion is to abusively call $f$ to 2 different functions. On one side you have $f$, function of 3 variables $x,y,z$, which you can derive with respect to any of those variables. On the other side you have a one variable function $g(t) = f(x(t),y(t),g(t))$, which you can derive with respect to $t$. The chain rule tells how you can compute the derivative of $g$ based on the derivatives of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consider different cases, don't confuse them :

FIRST CASE : $\quad f(x,y,z)$
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz$$

SECOND CASE : $\quad f(x(t),y(t),z(t))$

$dx=\frac{dx}{dt}dt \quad;\quad dy=\frac{dy}{dt}dt \quad;\quad dz=\frac{dz}{dt}dt$ .

$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}dt$

$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}$$

THIRD CASE : $\quad f(x,y,z,t)$
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt$$

FOURTH CASE : $\quad f(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)$

$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt$

$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$$
Don't confuse $\frac{df}{dt}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is the partial derivative of $f(x,y,z,t)$ with respect to $t$ with $x,y,z$ not function of $t$.

$\frac{df}{dt}$ is the total derivative of $f(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)$ with $x,y,z$ functions of $t$.

Comment: My doubt is, what do the partial derivative ∂/∂ mean, in case 2. x is a function of t, and so are y and z. While finding ∂/∂, we consider y and z to be constant while x is the variable quantity. But since in order to vary x, we shall have to vary t, which in turn will also change the other variables y and z. So, how does ∂/∂ hold true to its definition?

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is the derivative of $f(x,y,z,t)$ with respect to $x$ with $y,z,t$ not function of $x$. That is the definition. If latter on you make $x,y,z,t$ variable from any manner you want, the definition doesn't change. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ remains definitively the same function. If $x$ becomes a function of $t$ then the derivative with respect to $t$ becomes $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}$. Don't confuse with the derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: Thank you!! Got it!!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that initially you only had $f$ depending on $x,y,z$ and you had already computed the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$. Suddenly, you realize that in fact $x,y,z$ depend on a single variable $t$. How to compute $\frac{df}{dt}$ without throwing away the derivatives that you already computed? The answer is given by the formula that you mentioned.

Comment: But what do these partial derivate terms mean? According to the definition of partial derivatives, all the variables are to be kept unchanged which is simply not possible. Yet, we use something like ∂f/∂x. How does this interpretation hold true in this context? How are we still able to use partial derivates?

Comment: I'm afraid I dont' understand your question. When you compute for instance $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, the variables kept "unchanged" are just $y,z$, not $x$. For example $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2+y^2+z^2) = 2x$.

Comment: My doubt is, what do the partial derivative ∂/∂ mean when x is a function of t, and so are y and z. While finding ∂/∂, we consider y and z to be constant while x is the variable quantity. But since in order to vary x, we shall have to vary t, which in turn will also change the other variables y and z. So, how does ∂/∂ hold true to its definition in the formulation of total derivative?