# How does partial derivative make sense here?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

In my differential equation book, I have the following equation:

$$\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Here $y=g(x)$. So how does it make sense to say, $\left(    \text{in} \dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}     \right)$, we keep $y$ constant and change $x$?

[image]

Comment: Something is very wrong with the notation here.  You are using the symbol $f$ to be both a function of one variable (because you write $y=f(x)$) and a function of two variables (because you write $f(x,y)$).  Please clarify.

Comment: Let me show you the page from the book. It is exactly as I have written.

Comment: This is called an exact differential equation - consider $f_1(x,y)+f_2(x,y)\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} y=0$. You are looking for a potential $\varphi=\varphi(x,y(x))$ which satisfies $\nabla \varphi=f=(f_1,f_2)$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \varphi(x,y(x))=\partial_x \varphi(x,y(x))+\partial_y \varphi(x,y(x)) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} y(x)=f_1(x,y)+f_2(x,y) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} y(x)=0$.

Comment: What is the difference between $\dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{d \varphi}{dx}$? I ask this because in both cases $y$ cannot be constant as $y=f(x)$

Comment: Nowhere in the text does it say that $y=f(x)$, as you wrote.

Comment: Then what does $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ mean? Wouldn't it be zero then? making the equations meaningless. After all, solving a differential equation means expressing $y$ as a function of $x$. Isn't it?

Comment: $y$ is a function of $x$, but you should not use the symbol $f$ to denote it, because you are already using $f$ for something else.  Write something like $y=g(x)$ instead.  Anyway, I'm writing a more complete answer, give me a moment.

Comment: ok, sorry. That was a mistake. Let me correct it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notation is particularly confusing here (although not uncommon, unfortunately) because $x$ and $y$ are used in two very different ways.

In $\frac{dy}{dx}$, we are thinking of $y$ as a function of the variable $x$.  Let's write this as $y = g(x)$.

However, in the expressions $f(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$, these are *not* the same $x$ and $y$ above. $f$ is a function of two *independent* variables which we (unfortunately) are also calling $x$ and $y$.  Then $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ means: differentiate $f$ with respect to that first independent variable $x$, then substitute $(x,y)$ which are now our *original* (dependent) $x$ and $y$ related by $y = g(x)$.  This is all quite confusing, I agree.

A less confusing way to write it is as follows. Rename the independent variables in $f$.  Call them $s$ and $t$.  Then instead of writing $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$, write it as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(x,y)$, or even more explicitly, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}|_{s=x,t=y}$.  Now this is much clearer: We differentiate $f$, a function of two *independent* variables $s$ and $t$, with respect to the first variable $s$.  Then we substitute $s = x$ and $t = y$ into the result.  Now it should be clear that the fact that $x$ and $y$ are dependent doesn't matter.

Another way is to choose a different notation for partial derivatives that doesn't involve giving names to the independent variables at all, but instead just indicates them by position: $f_1$ means differentiate with respect to the first variable, $f_2$ with respect to the second variable.  Now we can just write $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please covert the equation $\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$ in my book in the language of your second last paragraph?

Comment: My try: $\left[   \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial s}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}\dfrac{dt}{ds} 
 \right]_{s=x,t=y}=0$

Comment: $\dfrac{dt}{ds}$ This doesn't make sense.

Comment: It would be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}|_{s=x,t=y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}|_{s=x,t=y} \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$. In this context, $s$ and $t$ are "dummy" variables used only to indicate differentiation within $f$, so they should not occur outside that context.  The actual variables you are working with in the problem are $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 5):

Many students encounter this difficulty to understand. This is due to a lack of mastery of total and partial derivative. You can find a detailed explanation in :
[What do the partial derivates mean in the formulation of total derivate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3100876/what-do-the-partial-derivates-mean-in-the-formulation-of-total-derivate/3100988?noredirect=1#comment6391963_3100988)

The total derivative of $f(x,y)$ is :
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy \tag 1$$
This is definitively true, even if $x$ and/or $y$ becomes fonction of another variable, for exemple $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. In this case $f(x,y)$ becomes a function of $t$, that is $f(x(t),y(t))$.

Then $dx=\frac{dx}{dt}dt$ and $dy=\frac{dy}{dt}dt$

Putting them into Eq.$(1)$ gives :
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}dt$$

The total derivative with respect to $t$ is :
$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

This is true whatever $t$ is, even if $t=x$.

In the case of $t=x$ , that is $f(x,y(x))$
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}$$

You wrote :

Here $y=f(x)$. So how does it make sense to say, $\left(    \text{in} \dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}     \right)$, we keep $y$ constant and change $x$?

Your first mistake is in $y=f(x)$ : this is false. You confuse the function $f(x,y(x))$ with the function $y=y(x)$.

Your second mistake is to think that $y$ is changed when computing $\left( \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)$, which should be the negation of the definition of partial derivative. Read again the above Eq.$(1)$ which is definitively true, even if $x$ and/or $y$ becomes fonction of another variable. At this step, $y$ is not yet function of $x$. Latter on, it is decided to make $y$ function of $x$. Then instead of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}$.